# Image upload from ckeditor to laravel local file system

Tags: javascript, json, laravel, ckeditor

Am trying to upload image using ckeditor to my local file system in laravel for which i made a code which is working fine image is uploading properly everything is working fine except in ckeditor it doesn't show link here is my code :

```
<script>
  window.onload = function() {
CKEDITOR.replace('long_description', {
 filebrowserUploadUrl: '{{ route('upload',['_token' => csrf_token() ]) }}'   

});

 };</script>
```

on the rote part i make a route for upload like this :

```
Route::post('upload_image','CkeditorController@uploadImage')->name('upload');
```

and in the controller part i use this code :

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;



class CkeditorController extends Controller
{
    public function uploadImage(Request $request) {
 $CKEditor = $request->input('CKEditor');
 $funcNum  = $request->input('CKEditorFuncNum');
 $message  = $url = '';
 if (Input::hasFile('upload')) {
 $file = Input::file('upload');
 if ($file->isValid()) {
 $filename =rand(1000,9999).$file->getClientOriginalName();
 $file->move(public_path().'/wysiwyg/', $filename);
 $url = url('wysiwyg/' . $filename);
 } else {
 $message = 'An error occurred while uploading the file.';
 }
 } else {
 $message = 'No file uploaded.';
 }
 return '<script>window.parent.CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction('.$funcNum.', "'.$url.'", "'.$message.'")</script>';
}
}
```

when i try to upload upload is working fine image goes in dir but in respose i got error :

```
[CKEDITOR] Error code: filetools-response-error. {responseText: "<script>window.parent.CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction(…linic/wysiwyg/4121dominospizza.jpg", "")</script>"}
```

so i search for error but i didn't get it  the error description was

```
An error occurred when parsing the upload response. Text could not be parsed to JSON.
Additional data:
responseText: Upload response text.
```

help me out please thanks in advance.